# Height doesn't work well in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I tested my page in FF, Chrome,...it works very good. But when I checking (using IE9), the height of search form doesn't full of parent height. Hope someone help me. Thank in advance.

Here is my code:

[Example code](http://codepen.io/thehung1724/pen/kCDEf)

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: I included my code. please check it